# State Reservation and Restoration iOS for ScanForPeripheral

Tags: ios, swift3, bluetooth-lowenergy, ibeacon

1. can State Reservation and restoration do `scanForPeripherals(withServices: nil, options: [CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey : true]` ?
2. my aim is to do scan, connect and write to peripheral from background.
   So far, I got that scanning in background needs specific service UUID. 
   Is there another way to do scanning etc in background without define service UUID ?

I'm using iBeacon and swift 3

Comment: It isn't clear what you are trying to achieve?  How can you connect to a peripheral and write to it if you don't know what service it is going to be advertising?

Comment: I'm trying to scan / discover peripheral without define the service uuid. I just make sure, that in background task behavior is different with foreground. In foreground we can connect to the peripheral even we dont know its service uuid but not in background. is that right ?

Comment: Correct. In the foreground you can use `nil` to discover all peripherals.

Comment: ok got it.. thanks Paul

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, no, if you do not supply a Service UUID, CoreBluetooth simply will not provide callbacks unless your app is in the foreground.

Comment: okay. Then, if I don't have service UUID, may I use kCBAdvDataLocalName to do scanning in background ?

Comment: No, you cannot scan by name. You need to know the specific service UUID you are scanning for in order to scan in the background. In fact, it is the discovery by iOS of a peripheral advertising the service UUID that you are scanning for that would cause your app to be relaunched for state restoration.

Comment: is ios and android have different way to do background scanning  ? Is Android need to know service UUID to do background task ? I'm using altbeacon plugin for android

Comment: Android is very different.  It does not need to know the service uuid when scanning in the background, although if you do provide it to a ScanFilter it will help save battery.  The Android Beacon Library does automatically provide the Eddystone service UUID to a ScanFilter in this case.